# Hibernate not setting foreign keys

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to save entities with `relationships`. I annotated the attributes but `hibernate` doesn´t use the parent key of the parent entity, it's always 0.

My first entity is a `TrafficJam` that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "traffic_jam", schema = "public", catalog = "dwh")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TrafficJamEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "traffic_jam_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="traffic_jam_seq")
  @SequenceGenerator(
        name="traffic_jam_seq",
        sequenceName="traffic_jam_id_sequence",
        allocationSize=1
  )
  private long trafficJamId;

  @Basic
  @Column(name = "reading_id")
  private long reading_id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trafficJamEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
  @Builder.Default
  private Set<DisturbanceCourseEntity> disturbanceCourseEntitySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

The child entity `DisturbanceCourse` looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "disturbance_course", schema = "public", catalog = "dwh")
@IdClass(DisturbanceCourseEntityPK.class)
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DisturbanceCourseEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "traffic_jam_id")
  private long trafficJamId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "traffic_jam_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = 
  false)
  private TrafficJamEntity trafficJamEntity;
}
```

If I add a disturbance course object to a traffic jam like this:

```
 trafficJamEntity.getDisturbanceCourseEntitySet().add(DisturbanceCourseEntity
                                            .builder()
                                            .latitude(latlong[0])
                                            .longitude(latlong[1])
                                            .orderNumber(shapeId)
                                            .build());
```

And try to save I get this error:

```
Fail to write to Database because: A different object with the same identifier value was 
already associated with the session 
[space.rocit.trafficetl.entities.DisturbanceCourseEntity#DisturbanceCourseEntityPK(trafficJamId=0, orderNumber=1)]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [space.rocit.trafficetl.entities.DisturbanceCourseEntity#DisturbanceCourseEntityPK(trafficJamId=0, orderNumber=1)]
```

I'm thinking that my definition of the relationship is wrong, any suggestions?

Edit.: 
Here is my DisturbanceCourseEntityPK Class:

```
@Data
public class DisturbanceCourseEntityPK implements Serializable {
private long trafficJamId;
private int orderNumber;
}
```

Edit 2.:
Yesterday i gave it another try and found out that the generated keys are set correctly when trying to save. The problem is in the setting of foreign keys with the @OnToMany Maping

Comment: Why trafficJamId is long instead of Long?

Comment: where is this class DisturbanceCourseEntityPK ?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov you are right i need to use Long here, I used the ORM Mapping from IntelliJ i don´t know why it used long here

Comment: maybe the id sequence table in your database is lagging behind the most recently generated id?  You are using `GeneratorType.SEQUENCE` so check the sequence table and see if the number in there is lower then the last id it generated. If so, manually update it with a number thats higher then the highest id currently used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbels upon this, this is the way to go.
The `TrafficJamEntity` needs to look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "traffic_jam", schema = "public", catalog = "dwh")
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TrafficJamEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "traffic_jam_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "traffic_jam_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "traffic_jam_seq", sequenceName = "traffic_jam_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private long trafficJamId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "trafficJamEntity", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<DisturbanceCourseEntity> disturbanceCourseEntitySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

And the child entity `Disturbance Course` needs to look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "disturbance_course", schema = "public", catalog = "dwh")
@IdClass(DisturbanceCourseEntityPK.class)
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DisturbanceCourseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "traffic_jam_id")
    private TrafficJamEntity trafficJamEntity;

}
```

The  `@Column(name = "traffic_jam_id")` Attribute of my question is unnecessary because the `@ID` Annotation does the same.

Also the binding between the parent-child objects needs to be bidirectional so its not

```
 trafficJamEntity.getDisturbanceCourseEntitySet().add(DisturbanceCourseEntity
                                            .builder()
                                            .latitude(latlong[0])
                                            .longitude(latlong[1])
                                            .orderNumber(shapeId)
                                            .build());
```

but

```
DisturbanceCourseEntity disturbanceCourseEntity = DisturbanceCourseEntity
        .builder()
        .latitude(latitude)
        .longitude(longitude)
        .orderNumber(shapeId)
        .trafficJamEntity(trafficJamEntity)
        .build();

trafficJamEntity.getDisturbanceCourseEntitySet().add(disturbanceCourseEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

instead on traffic_jam_id Generated Value notation change like this,

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Check it :)